# Shiny - app loads but it does not read the data file

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I am trying to build my first shiny app in which I want my app to read different files based on user selected inputs. I have managed to build the ui.R, server.R, and helper.R functions so that I am not getting errors but my app is not working i.e. the file does not load. Nothing happens when I select different inputs, it appears that my read file function in my Helper.R script is not working. I have been stuck on this for days and I would very much appreciate some help to get this working.

## ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel(“Search RSQRM Asset Data”),

fluidRow(

column(3,
selectInput(“model”, label = h3(“Select Model”),
choices = c(“RSQRM Global”, “RSQRM Europe”,”RSQRM US”,”RSQRM Japan”,”RSQRM Asia ex-JP”), selected = ‘RSQRM Global’)),

column(3,
selectInput(“modelCurrency”, label = h3(“Select Model Currency”),
choices = c(“USD”,”EUR”,”JPY”), selected = ‘EUR’)),

column(3,
dateInput(“modelDate”,
label = h3(“Select Model Date”),
value = “2014-04-23″)),

column(3,
radioButtons(“modelVersion”, label = h3(“L or G Version”),
choices = c(“Local Currency Exposure”, “Global Currency Exposure”),selected = “Local Currency Exposure”)),

helpText(“Note: Select the correct combination of model region and base currency.”),

submitButton(“Update View”)
),

# Create a new row for the table.
fluidRow(
dataTableOutput(outputId=”assetData”)
)

))
```

=============

## server.R

```
   library(timeDate);library(data.table)
source("helper.R")

# Define a server for the Shiny app
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    sModelPath<-'T:/Documents/Rsquared/RSQRM/'

    #Assign switch values for the input fields
    dfAssetData <- reactive({

                        sModel <- switch(input$model, "RSQRM Global"==as.character('GlobalDev'),
                                         "RSQRM Europe"=as.character('Europe'),
                                         "RSQRM US"=as.character('US'),
                                         "RSQRM Japan"=as.character('Japan'),
                                         "RSQRM Asia ex-JP"=as.character('AsiaExJP'))

                        sModelCurrency <- switch(input$modelCurrency, "USD"=as.character('USD'),"EUR"=as.character('EUR'),"JPY"=as.character('JPY'))

                        sModelVersion <- switch( input$modelVersion, "Local Currency Exposure"="", "Global Currency Exposure"=as.character("_G"))

                        sModelDate <- input$modelDate

                        readAssetDataFile(sModelPath=sModelPath,sModel=sModel,sModelCurrency=sModelCurrency,sModelDate=sModelDate,sModelVersion=sModelVersion)
                        })


    output$assetData <- renderDataTable(
        dfAssetData,options=list(iDisplayLength = 25)
        )

})
```

=============

## helper.R

```
# Constructs File Path and reads File

    readAssetDataFile <- function(sModelPath,sModel,sModelCurrency,sModelDate,sModelVersion)
    {
    #Build Model file path
    if(sModel=='GlobalDev')
    {
    sModelFile<-paste(sModelPath,sModel,'/outputData/','FF_RSQ_RSQRM_GlobalDev_v2_19_8_',sModelCurrency,'_',format(sModelDate,"%Y%m%d"),'_AssetData.txt',sep='')
    } else if(sModel=='Europe')
    {
    sModelFile<-paste(sModelPath,sModel,'/outputData/','FF_RSQ_RSQRM_Europe',sModelVersion,'_v2_19_9_',sModelCurrency,'_',format(sModelDate,"%Y%m%d"),'_AssetData.txt',sep='')
    } else if(sModel=='US')
    {
    sModelFile<-paste(sModelPath,sModel,'/outputData/','FF_RSQRM_US_v2_19_7_',sModelCurrency,'_',format(sModelDate,"%Y%m%d"),'_AssetData.txt',sep='')
    } else if(sModel=='Japan')
    {
    sModelFile<-paste(sModelPath,sModel,'/outputData/','FF_RSQ_RSQRM_Japan_v2_19_4_',sModelCurrency,'_',format(sModelDate,"%Y%m%d"),'_AssetData.txt',sep='')
    } else if(sModel=='AsiaExJP')
    {
    sModelFile<-paste(sModelPath,sModel,'/outputData /','FF_RSQ_RSQRM_AsiaExJP_v2_19_6_',sModelCurrency,'_',format(sModelDate,"%Y%m%d"),'_AssetData.txt',sep='')
    }

    #Read Asset Data File
    dfDataHeader<-t(scan(sModelFile,skip=2,nlines=1,what = 'character',sep='|'))
    dfData<-read.csv(sModelFile,sep='|',skip=3,header=F,stringsAsFactors=F)
    names(dfData)<-dfDataHeader
    return(dfData)
    }
```

=============

## extract of one of the source files

Asset Data|RSQRM_GlobalDev_v2_19_8_EUR
Date|20140423
RSQID|Parent ID|Currency Of Quotation|Domicile|Exchange Country|ADR|Current Price|Local Mkt Cap|Name|Return|Specific Return|Model R-Squared|Historical Variance|Model Variance|Base Currency Mkt Cap
AED||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.272242|0|United Arab Dirham|-0.00525701|-1.019239e-005|0.9999894|0.008664313|0.01005771|0
ARS||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.1249497|0|Argentine Peso|-0.004397333|0|1|0.01426818|0.01750348|0
AUD||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.9287573|0|Australian Dollar|0.006424189|0|1|0.01322997|0.01398572|0
BRL||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.4455243|0|Brazilian Real|0.03908932|0|1|0.01858497|0.01901002|0
BWP||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.1141982|0|Botswana Pula|0.01457977|0.01029778|0.8950179|0.0081137|0.008672097|0
CAD||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.9057439|0|Canadian Dollar|0.01092219|0|1|0.007959329|0.008564582|0
CHF||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|1.133649|0|Swiss Franc|0.00140202|0|1|0.003511256|0.005111289|0
CLP||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.001774098|0|Chilean Peso|-0.03123808|0|1|0.01214774|0.01481514|0
CNY||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.160308|0|Chinese Yuan Renminbi|-0.01323205|0|1|0.008269959|0.009692453|0
COP||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.0005161191|0|COLOMBIAN PESO|0.03332853|0|1|0.01231008|0.01293377|0
EGP||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.1429034|0|Egyptian Pound|-0.01327199|-0.00800544|0.9377586|0.01042045|0.01099546|0
EUR||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|1.38284|0|EURO|0|0|0|0|0|0
GBP||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|1.6778|0|POUNDS STERLING|0.01696134|0|1|0.005241998|0.005920209|0
HKD||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.1289722|0|Hong Kong Dollar|-0.003935099|0.001270294|0.9993091|0.008515768|0.009881006|0
HUF||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.004495231|0|Hungarian Forint|0.0242871|0|1|0.01060005|0.009236147|0
IDR||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|8.598194e-005|0|Indonesian Rupiah|-0.03087831|0|1|0.01365197|0.01479055|0
ILS||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.2871667|0|Israeli Shekel|-0.0003501177|0|1|0.006951562|0.006442094|0
INR||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.01635841|0|Indian Rupee|-0.03235179|0|1|0.01130393|0.01236205|0
ISK||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.008922095|0|Icelandic Krona|0.0171473|0.03882897|0.297565|0.04469517|0.04829158|0
JPY||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.00976686|0|Japanese Yen|-0.00645864|0|1|0.01881293|0.01908195|0
KRW||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.0009616939|0|South Korean Won|0.05476844|0|1|0.009969143|0.01028664|0
KWD||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|3.555414|0|Kuwaiti Dinar|-0.002247274|0.002172351|0.9813095|0.006397537|0.007210578|0
KZT||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.005493779|0|Kazakhstan Tenge|-0.004944563|0.01499879|0.807177|0.01728362|0.02166266|0
LTL||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.4005443|0|Lithuanian Litas|0.000264883|0.0002661943|0.1098195|4.386074e-006|1.170735e-005|0
MXN||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.07643005|0|Mexican Nuevo Peso|0.0002846718|0|1|0.01561729|0.01448273|0
MYR||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.3061288|0|Malaysian Ringgit|0.01157045|0|1|0.008959501|0.009135634|0
NAD||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.09418435|0|Namibia Dollar|0.005982637|-0.001955748|0.9904171|0.02083048|0.01997479|0
NOK||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.1668374|0|Norwegian Krone|0.009662986|0|1|0.004682287|0.004911323|0
NZD||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.8582975|0|New Zealand Dollar|-0.009660542|0|1|0.01219613|0.01205033|0
PEN||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.3584124|0|Peruvian Nuevo Sol|0.009532809|0|1|0.01369225|0.01090846|0
PHP||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.02233582|0|Philippine Peso|0.0008690357|0|1|0.008781091|0.009171846|0
PLN||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.3299508|0|Polish New Zloty|-0.003601432|0|1|0.008027087|0.007835649|0
QAR||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.2746395|0|Qatari Rial|-0.004940689|0.0003093481|0.9999509|0.008670089|0.01006616|0
RON||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.3093118|0|ROMANIAN LEU (NEW)|0.0001454353|0|1|0.002584549|0.003188807|0
RSD||USD|#N/A|#N/A|0|0.01196992|0|Serbia Dinar|0.002955198|0.002888322|0.3149524|0.005209823|0.005366478|0
RSQ00100301|RSQP001003|USD|US|US|0|0|0|A.A. IMPORTING CO INC|0|0|0.2278523|0.5409994|0.6483656|0.0388042
RSQ00100401|RSQP001004|USD|US|US|0|26.61|0|AAR CORP|0.03524399|-0.0009624362|0.6713049|0.1861986|0.1837458|761.4265
RSQ00101901|RSQP001019|USD|US|US|0|275|0|AFA PROTECTIVE SYSTEMS INC|-0.005258679|-0.01361179|0.546496|0.03353066|0.04896197|38.38115
RSQ00102101|RSQP001021|USD|US|US|0|3|0|AFP IMAGING CORP|-0.005258679|0.01126492|0.2947952|1.234856|1.125692|0.07810013
RSQ00104501W|RSQP001045|MXN|US|MX|0|460|0|AMERICAN AIRLINES GROUP INC|-0.107383|-0.1256154|0.2745233|0.544104|0.552039|19222.34
RSQ00104504|RSQP001045|USD|US|US|0|36.16|0|AMERICAN AIRLINES GROUP INC|-0.03031355|-0.05283874|0.342698|0.6602146|0.4509373|12329.74
RSQ00105001|RSQP001050|USD|US|US|0|16.69|0|CECO ENVIRONMENTAL CORP|0.0177182|-0.01030165|0.4680261|0.1776531|0.1898829|309.8809
RSQ00107201|RSQP001072|USD|US|US|0|13.39|0|AVX CORP|0.04942906|0.04780984|0.7066215|0.04772019|0.05692234|1628.753
RSQ00107501|RSQP001075|USD|US|US|0|55.6|0|PINNACLE WEST CAPITAL CORP|0.03970087|-0.02854544|0.8831447|0.03975214|0.0374972|4436.935
RSQ00107601|RSQP001076|USD|US|US|0|30.13|0|AARON'S INC|-0.02922386|-0.02090919|0.5094755|0.07882757|0.07039738|1568.27
RSQ00107801|RSQP001078|USD|US|US|0|38.6|0|ABBOTT LABORATORIES|0.006312132|0.03443837|0.4539649|0.09144053|0.08155435|43072.59
RSQ00107801W|RSQP001078|USD|US|GB|0|38.62|0|ABBOTT LABORATORIES|-0.002148151|0.006967425|0.2366017|0.08802702|0.1942208|43094.9
RSQ00107802W|RSQP001078|CHF|US|CH|0|33.75|0|ABBOTT LABORATORIES|-0.02139831|-0.09285313|0.2569895|0.4222401|0.2419817|42693.91
RSQ00108401|RSQP001084|USD|US|US|0|0.157|0|WORLDS INC|0.07596767|0.06546307|0.4029619|1.849886|1.528729|10.58255
RSQ00109401|RSQP001094|USD|US|US|0|21.77|0|ACETO CORP|0.1782798|0.1492193|0.6505797|0.1856081|0.1646115|446.7853

## RSQ00109601|RSQP001096|USD|CA|US|0|117.8482|0|ACKTON CORP|0.05328643|-0.01130325|1|0.07294457|0.02986959|1066.637

Answer (score 0):

When you call a reactive variable, call it as you would when calling a function.

For example, in your output$assetData when you call dfAssetData, try this...

```
    output$assetData <- renderDataTable(
        dfAssetData(),options=list(iDisplayLength = 25)
    )
```

There may be more to the problem but that is the first error I see.